# Parse img and alt from div using JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup

I have div element with class "`slides sqs-gallery-design-autocolumns`" which consists a lot of div elements with class "`slide sqs-gallery-design-autocolumns-slide`". Each element has an `img` and an `alt` tag. 
How I can parse and get collection of images (Class Image: string - url, string - name) using JSOUP library?

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujO6A.png) - clickable

Comment: Can you please add your code thus far?

Comment: already already already